# Facebook feed, twitter twits and linked connection in php website

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

Is this possible to show Facebook feeds, twitter twits and LinkedIn connection on a pages without entering user secrete key of Facebook,twitter and ln account?

I want just enter Facebook,twitter and ln user account id after that fb feeds,twits and ln connection will show on page.

Let me know if this possible and it's legal?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Did you try googling first before coming to StackOverflow?

#### Facebook Feed Parser

- https://gist.github.com/banago/3864515

#### Twitter Feed Parser

- http://blog.jacobemerick.com/web-development/parsing-twitter-feeds-with-php/

As for the linkedin connections; it doesn't seem to be possible without using their API:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/reading-data#toggleview:id=php

However, if you want to parse the profile (public data) without API, you're in luck:
http://icorbin.com/linkedin-api-open-source/465#.U2DGWVdRwtU